# Do two waves propagating in different directions on the same line induce a standing wave?

Tags: waves, superposition

What is the mathematical proof for this?

Comment: It is not always true: For instance, if the waves have different amplitude or different frequency  they will not form a standing wave

Comment: @AlbertAspect How can you show this?

Comment: program it and view the result

Comment: -1. No research effort. A citation for "I heard it was true always" would be useful! See [Standing waves due to two counter-propagating travelling waves of different amplitude](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265298).

Comment: @sammygerbil Your link does not include mathematical derivation. I heard it was true from a TA which is totally irrelevant. "No research effort" Wrong, unless you can pull up my search history and prove otherwise

Comment: It is not for us to hack into your computer to investigate your search history. The onus is on you to show effort in your question. Hover the pointer over the down-vote to see what the purpose is. ... For a mathematical derivation see [how to add two plane waves if they are propagating in different direction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69587)

Comment: Have you tried adding the two waves for yourself and seeing the math?

Answer (score 2):

Wave going into positive direction has the equation:

$$p(x)=\sin(x+\omega t)$$

Into the negative direction:

$$n(x)=\sin(x-\omega t)$$

Their sum:

\begin{align}
p(x)+n(x)&=\sin(x+\omega t)+\sin(x-\omega t) \\ 
&=\sin(x)\cos(\omega t) + \cos(x)\sin(\omega t) + \sin(x)\cos(\omega t) - \cos(x)\sin(\omega t)\\
&=2 sin(x)cos(\omega t)
\end{align}

As you can see, the wave on the bottom is a *standing* sine wave, whose amplitude is multiplied by the original frequency of the moving waves.